# Oracle | missing expression error inside Insert Procedure

Tags: database, oracle

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

drop table tbl_Termin;
drop table tbl_Arzt;


drop sequence seq_Arzt_id;
drop sequence seq_Termin_id;

create sequence seq_Arzt_id
    start with 1
    Increment by 1
/

create sequence seq_Termin_id
    start with 1
    increment by 1
/

create table tbl_Arzt(
 ID_Arzt number primary key,
 vorname varchar2(50),
 nachname varchar2(50)
);

create table tbl_Termin(
    ID_Termin number primary key,
    ID_Arzt number,
    datum DATE,
    zeit DATE,
    beschreibung varchar2(50),
    foreign key (ID_Arzt) references tbl_Arzt(ID_Arzt)
);

create or replace trigger tri_Arzt_id
before insert on tbl_Arzt
for each row
begin
:new.ID_Arzt := seq_Arzt_id.nextval; 
end;
/

create or replace trigger tri_Termin_id
before insert on tbl_Termin
for each row
begin
:new.ID_Termin := seq_Termin_id.nextval; 
end;
/

create or replace procedure pro_datenEinfuegen(
    p_vorname varchar2, 
    p_nachname varchar2,
    p_datum DATE,
    p_zeit DATE,
    p_beschreibung varchar2
) AS
    v_id_Arzt number;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_Arzt(ID_Arzt, vorname, nachname)
    VALUES (NULL, p_vorname, p_nachname)
    RETURNING ID_Arzt INTO v_id_Arzt;

    INSERT INTO tbl_Termin(ID_Termin, ID_Arzt, datum, zeit, beschreibung) 
    VALUES (NULL, v_id_Arzt, TO_DATE(p_datum, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE(p_zeit, 'HH24:MI:SS'), p_beschreibung);
    
    COMMIT;
end;
/

CALL pro_datenEinfuegen('vorname','nachname','03-09-2024','12:50:00','zaehne')
```

I had countered an error on my projectscript for my database, which tells me that I got an issue with the procedure that Im using for my INSERT into the tables.
Now the real problem is that I dont know what I've done wrong, because im still learning.
Would appreciate any help.

I already added a data format mask which did also not help,

Comment: As posted your procedure *call* will throw "ORA-01843: An invalid month was specified." If you change the procedure definition to pass in strings instead of dates  (as your `to_date()` suggest you meant) [then it doesn't error](https://dbfiddle.uk/sZvBQfxh). Please make sure you give a [mre] that is what you actually run and gets the error you say - and give the full error please. (Also why are you storing date and time as separate columns?)

Answer (score 1):

1. In Oracle, a `DATE` always has both date and time components so you can combine the `datum` and `zeit` columns:

   ```sql
   create table tbl_Termin(
       ID_Termin number primary key,
       ID_Arzt number,
       datum DATE,
       beschreibung varchar2(50),
       foreign key (ID_Arzt) references tbl_Arzt(ID_Arzt)
   );
   ```
2. Don't call `TO_DATE` on something that is already a `DATE`.

   ```sql
   create or replace procedure pro_datenEinfuegen(
       p_vorname varchar2, 
       p_nachname varchar2,
       p_datum DATE,
       p_beschreibung varchar2
   ) AS
       v_id_Arzt number;
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tbl_Arzt(ID_Arzt, vorname, nachname)
       VALUES (NULL, p_vorname, p_nachname)
       RETURNING ID_Arzt INTO v_id_Arzt;

       INSERT INTO tbl_Termin(ID_Termin, ID_Arzt, datum, beschreibung) 
       VALUES (NULL, v_id_Arzt, p_datum, p_beschreibung);
   end;
   /
   ```

   *Note: You should not `COMMIT` in the procedure as it prevents you chaining multiple procedures together and then if there is an error in a later procedure using `ROLLBACK` to revert them all. Instead, you should `COMMIT` from the code where you call the procedure(s).*
3. Then you can call the procedure:

   ```sql
   CALL pro_datenEinfuegen('vorname', 'nachname', DATE '2024-09-03' + INTERVAL '0 12:50:00' DAY TO SECOND, 'zaehne')
   ```

   or:

   ```sql
   CALL pro_datenEinfuegen('vorname', 'nachname', TIMESTAMP '2024-09-03 12:50:00', 'zaehne')
   ```

   or:

   ```sql
   CALL pro_datenEinfuegen('vorname', 'nachname', TO_DATE('09-03-2024 12:50:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'zaehne')
   ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qmrCyOc8)